# WTL: To process certain commands in certain command handlers

Tags: windows, visual-c++, wtl

I'm a new in WTL.

One of the classes of a project I'm working on is WTL GUI class. Its message map contains a record:

```
COMMAND_CODE_HANDLER(0, OnMenuClick)
```

`OnMenuClick` handles all `WM_COMMAND`'s are sent after menu click. Is there way to set another command handlers for some certain messages, while `OnMenuClick` processes all other ones?

I tried this:

```
COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_START_TASK, OnStartTask);
COMMAND_CODE_HANDLER(0, OnMenuClick)
```

It works, `OnStartTask` processes `ID_START_TASK` commands, but it depends on declaration order. If i change the strings declaration order, `OnMenuClick` processes `ID_START_TASK` commands.

I use VS 2008 + WTL 8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [COMMAND_HANDLER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsxbs7hc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> The message map sets bHandled to TRUE before CommandHandler is called.
>   If CommandHandler does not fully handle the message, it should set
>   bHandled to FALSE to indicate the message needs further processing.

WTL calls handlers as long as none of them signalled that they handled the message.
If the handler doesn't explicitly set bHandled to FALSE, WTL will not pass the message to the next handler.

Comment: As far as i know, ``bHandled`` is set in ``true`` by default. So, the only thing i need to do is set it in ``false`` in ``OnMenuClick`` in the case of ``ID_START_TASK`` command, am i right?

Comment: Yep. It's probably a good idea to make a habit out of setting it to FALSE and only set it to TRUE if you have to make sure no other handler processes it.